# Bounding Box in Image Difference in Video

Tags: algorithm, opencv, image-processing, bounding-box

I am trying to find the bounding box of objects in video frames. I assume the present bounding box detection finds the objects in raw frames, while I want to extract bounding box in Frame Difference. In the image below, I have subtracted background from the frame and the result is right image.

[image]

Since most of the pixels in frame difference is going to be zero, I am assuming the bounding box detection for this should be computationally cheap.

Comment: Start a BFS or DFS from every white pixel (unless you already visited it) and calculate the bounding boxes of the reached pixels. Optionally, perform morphological closing before that to get rid of small islands.

Comment: The thing is Image Difference is not that clean. There are few pixels which are not zero because of some light change and if I do BFS then they might connect two objects also. Should I use some sort of smoothing of video frames ?

Comment: Then perform binarization before (e.g. with a simple thresholding approach).

Comment: I assume by binarization u mean converting pixels into binary intensity. Right?

Comment: Yes, a 0/1 intensity (either white or black).

Comment: Even before applying Image Difference, should I do some other cleaning/smoothing of frames ?

Comment: If you want your output to be cleaner, smooth the difference image a bit before thresholding. You can also smooth the result of the thresholding, but it is always easier to do before.

Comment: Also note that a BFS (or any other search) is way more expensive than using a proper UnionFind labeling algorithm. You've tagged OpenCV, use the stuff that is there, don't reinvent the wheel! (see my answer).

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yeah I think BFS is going to be more expensive that Union Find.

Comment: Related and maybe informative https://stackoverflow.com/q/50902373/2836621

Comment: Plenty of people have made this comparison and found various UnionFind implementations to be faster. See for example here: https://github.com/prittt/YACCLAB

Answer (score 1):

You didn't tag with a specific language, so I'll give a pseudo-code answer, with pointers to OpenCV functions to use:

1. Fill gaps if you want to make sure disjoint regions that are close together get assigned to the same box: [`morphologyEx`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga67493776e3ad1a3df63883829375201f) with the `MORPH_CLOSE` operation, and using a small kernel.
2. Connected component analysis: [`connectedComponents`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gaedef8c7340499ca391d459122e51bef5). This leads to an integer image where all pixels for each "object" are painted with the same value (label).
3. Find minimum and maximum of x and y coordinate for each label. You can combine this step with the previous one in OpenCV using [`connectedComponentsWithStats`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga107a78bf7cd25dec05fb4dfc5c9e765f), and getting the `CC_STAT_LEFT`, `CC_STAT_TOP`, `CC_STAT_WIDTH` and `CC_STAT_HEIGHT` columns of the `stats` output.

Yes, this is pretty cheap.

Comment: The whole motivation of doing bounding box detection for image difference is that it should be cheaper than the bounding box detection for a raw Image. Can you throw some light on the comparison of computational complexity ?

Comment: I can use above functions to get bounding box for any image(not specific frame difference), as connectedComponents will label pixels for an object. And I can use your step 3 to get the bounding box. How come this is cheaper?

Comment: @random_28: I'm not sure what you mean here. Yes, this is the standard way of finding bounding boxes of objects in binary images. If you don't do the background comparison, which yields a binary output, you'll have a grey-value (or RGB?) image, and you can't use connected component analysis on that. You need to apply some sort of object detection, which is computationally expensive. Background subtraction is the cheapest form of object detection I know of...

Comment: Is this the standard and known way to do bounding box detection in VIDEO frames? I mean to take the background frame and take frame diff ?

Comment: @random_28: There are two different issues here: (1) object detection, and (2) finding the bounding box for the objects. (1) can be solved with the background subtraction. (2) should be solved with connected component analysis. You had already solved (1), and were asking how to do (2), so I answered about how to do (2). These two tasks are orthogonal. You can solve (1) in another way, for example with deep CNNs, but then you still need to do (2), and the approach outlined here is the way to do this.

Comment: @CrisLuenge: This clarifies things. Let me try implementing this thing.